# Hardware to run a fixed neural network

Tags: power, hardware, asic

Suppose I have a feedforward neural network and I already have decided what its directed graph, weights and activation function should be. I want a device than runs this neural network as quickly as possible, with secondary considerations being size of the device, power consumption and cost. What is the best hardware design for this purpose? Have there been cases of say ASICs being built for a particular neural network?

To give a rough idea my network has around one million neurons and ten billion connections.

Comment: Your neural network demands CPU/GPU level of performance to run at any acceptable rate. With 8-bit weights you already have GB of data for that alone. I think your best bet (if you are set on such a huge network) would be to load weights progressively from external memory, do the linear algebra and feed the result through the activation function, i.e. calculate one layer at a time. My suggestion is to simplify the network; if it is going to run on dedicated hardware, and you want to keep cost as low as possible/manageable I don't think you have any other choice.

Comment: Check Coral's AI modules. They run Tensor flow. Also ST's Cube AI allows to integrate pre-trained networks into its microcontroller codes. They have some powerful microcontrollers like STM32H7 but I gues those wouldn't come near the scale of your application.

Answer (score 6):

> To give a rough idea my network has around one million neurons and ten billion connections.

That means ten billion weights. From a NN perspective, this very much sounds like you want to apply L1 regularization to reduce the number of connections; unless you really have good reasons why this needs to be this large, I'm almost certain that you didn't sufficiently optimize your network.

Anyway, in its current form, you'd need something to store 10 billion coefficients. The only realistic way of doing that is using SDRAM.

Then, you need an SDRAM controller.

And then, you need something to fetch the data from that controller and execute your inference.

In other word, you're describing a large GPU. So, you need a large GPU. A GPU these days essentially **is** an ASIC for NN applications. The whole graphics aspects of it can be safely ignored.

Comment: but could there be a dedicated electronic circuit or transistor simulating a given synapse for example? So that I could write the weights in at the manufacturing stage. I am OK with zero flexibility (and yes there are some reasons for the network to be this large).

Comment: yes, that electronic circuit is called a "GPU". As said.

Comment: I mean, a GPU can be used to run many different neural networks with different architectures and weights so it seems incredibly inefficient cost-wise. I was thinking of something where there would no need to get the weights from a central memory location because the hardware parallels the NN on a deeper level (but maybe that's not possible).

Comment: hahaha, it's incredibly cheap! Look at this: A modern 64-core CPU (Zen 2, for example), has around 4 billion transistors, so at least 2 or 3 orders of magnitude less than what you would need, even if your weights only had 2 bit! These CPUs are pretty expensive. Also, they only fit on your mainboard because their structures are very small. The cost of producing the mask to produce such a CPU is in the order of 10 Million dollars. You don't even get access to the equipment to produce such a device. So, no, you're totally off.

Comment: You are certainly right if we talk from a single consumer's point of view but I mean theoretically if there was sufficient demand and all the fixed costs are ignored do you think a dedicated device could be cheaper than a GPU? If say some tech giant absorbed the initial overhead.

Comment: Special interconnected node computational hardware has been tried before and what keeps happening is that technology of general application makes a generational step past the painstakingly built spin of special technology making it obsolete, and it never worked well enough to justify a respin.  Also, the problem isn't the computation but the interconnect.  Time-slicing a (somewhat more) general processor to handle many nodes also makes the interconnect between them a lot simpler to implement since it's already getting its fingers into the the state of a whole lot of them.

Comment: @crispr I really don't think you'd sell anything in larger numbers than x86 CPUs, and even then, exactly what Chris writes would be true: for a marginal gain in the short run, you'd bury millions and millions of dollars. I don't see what sense that would make. Also, again, I'm almost certain you're missing something, and your neural net is totally misdesigned, or your problem is actually IO-bound and can't even get the data in and out fast enough.

Comment: @crispr the reason why I said the only realistic way to do this was SDRAM is because no other fast technology even comes close to the cheapness per bit. And then, you're really in the situation where you need a mass memory SDRAM controller, the SDRAM separate from your activation functions, and don't gain anything from your fixed-function implementation. Also, there's very real limits on how many transistors you can switch at once on a IC before you can no longer transport away the heat.

Comment: @crispr I think the point is that 10 billion weights is so many that you can't make a dedicated circuit for these 10 billion weights. You will need to make a generic circuit, and make it process some of the weights at a time.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to implement a neural network in hardware, you need to **prune** your neural network first.

It is not a good idea to implement a fixed neural network as an ASIC which has no option for reprogrammability as the requirements of your application are likely to be modified in the future.

Deep Learning is well suited for parallel architectures. 2 options for hardware which is inherently parallel are GPUs and FPGAs. Read [this paper](https://www.nvidia.ca/docs/IO/67189/che_sasp08.pdf) to see which of the two are best suited for your application.

Since your application is computed at the edge, I would recommend the FPGA since it has lower latency when compared to a GPU.

FPGAs are reprogrammable and have computing, logic, and memory resources in a single device. FPGAs have built in blocks for DSP, so they can **efficiently perform convolution operations**.

The reason why GPUs are preferred over FPGAs is because most AI scientists come from a software background and are familiar with GPU based parallel programming using CUDA and until recently FPGAs had to be programmed using Hardware Description Languages only.

But now, they don't have to be programmed using HDLs. You can also use High Level Synthesis tools or OpenCL or other software like Vitis or OpenVino. **And** you can reconfigure the hardware to efficiently execute algorithms if necessary (in some cases it will be necessary).

You can also consider using an accelerator which is based on FPGA (like Xilinx's Alveo.)

**Sources**:

1. https://www.intel.in/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/solution-sheets/efficient_neural_networks.pdf
2. https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp504-accel-dnns.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the list of new ways to program FPGA's. We're using Verilog which you didn't mention, but I consider it easier to use than VHDL for implementing algorithms. Any updates, after 2 years?

Answer (score 1):

There are some ASIC starting to go on the market for AI application, it is usually called TPU (Tensor Processing Unit) or Edge TPU for hardware.

Notably, [there is one from Google](https://cloud.google.com/edge-tpu) and another Chinese company called Sophon from Bitmain with several products [like this one](https://www.sophon.ai/product/introduce/sm5.html)

[image]

Note that those products are fairly recent and not mature, so it might be difficult to implement.

They have either chips or modules, depending on if you intend to do your own design.

There are many different solutions, but depends a lot on your requirements, which are not very clear (size, power, etc..)

Comment: but TPU is designed for training networks not running them (as far as I know). Well, I mean it can run them as well but is not necessarily most efficient to buy a TPU to run a network

Comment: @crispr The answer links to the TPU variant designed for running, not training networks. Take a look at what it does before you decide it won't work.

Comment: @user1850479 oops my bad

Answer (score -2):

You have not specified the update speed at the synaptic connections.

I use 0.0001 seconds for our mental processes, particularly in the retina.

Thus 1Billion neurons for visual_cortex processing, with perhaps 100,000 synapse into each tree, updating at 10,000 Hz rate === is a computational load.

With the need for 3_D connectivity.

For about a watt of power for these measly 1Billion.

The finest pulse timing resolution, allowing dense correlation of information_bearing pulse trains, is about 0.0001 second.

With about 8 bit math; and nonlinearity to compress the correlator outputs.

Thus the self-driving car challenge is: 1B neurons, 100,000 synapses per neuron, updating 10,000X per second ===> 10^ 18 per second 8-bit math.

With all the 3_D connectivity.

===============================================

Encountered some GOOGLE test_drivers at local airport. I brought my own experiments, decades ago, in autonomous machines. We got to sharing results.

The current GOOGLE machines will freeze up if anything is moving in an intersection; thus pieces of paper cause a FREEZE response, so the GOOGLE machines can continue to proclaim "We don't cause accidents".

Part of the horrid behavior, given the very low resolution of the visual sensors, and the LIDAR sensors, results from lack of 3_D modeling and prediction of optic_flows that would reduce the need to rebuild the vectors upon each newly arrived frame.

Comment: I find it hard to follow the thread of thought in this answer. What hardware are you referring to? The human brain? It seems to me that the synaptic weight resolution in human brains is around 5 bit, not 8 bit. Also what relation does th self-driving car challenge have to the topic at hand? And why are you including only the visual cortex in the calculation? When a human drives, the motor skills are also included and sometimes moral decisions (if a human sees a deer or a child on the road for long enough to consciously process it). And what is a tree in this context?